# Is there a way to change the size of the custom white balance sampling area on Fujifilm X cameras?

Tags: white-balance, fujifilm, camera-controls, fujifilm-xt10

Like many cameras, my Fujifilm X-T10 has a feature to set white balance by framing a white object and clicking the shutter. From [the manual](http://fujifilm-dsc.com/en/manual/x-t10/shooting/white_balance/index.html):

> White balance measurement options will be displayed; frame a white object so that it fills the display and press the shutter button all the way down to measure white balance.

Although the text says "fills the display", there's actually rectangle centered in the screen, taking up about one quarter. On my previous (Pentax) camera, it was possible to adjust the size of this rectangle, which I found very handy when a very large or close-by white area wasn't available. Turning the dials on my Fujifilm camera in this mode doesn't seem to do anything — am I out of luck?

If this lower-end model doesn't have the feature but higher-end models do, I'd like to know that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done.  The Fuji X-Pro 2, the current top-of-the-line model does not offer that ability.  You'll have to move closer or back, or use a filter designed to give a "whole scene" white balance filter.